# Will the support for jQuery 3 be added?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm trying to use the jQuery Chosen library with the image-select plugin in Drupal, but I can't get the element to render correctly. The example page uses jQuery 3 and Drupal 8 doesn't.

Will Drupal 8 support jQuery 3?

Comment: Drupal doesn't require jQuery any more, so it's already supported. You just need to add it to the page via a library

Comment: Hi Clive, got a link to some docs on how to  accomplish this? (for reference) Thanks!

Comment: He literally just means to add the file using a library, just as you would add any JS file in Drupal.  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ongoing discussion on the Drupal core issue queue: [Update jQuery to version 3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2533498).

The issue has been marked fixed on August 1, 2017. The patch has been committed on Drupal 8.4.x and Drupal 8.5.x.

Answer (score 1):

As Clive said, you can add whatever version of jQuery you want to a page. However, there's an issue here worth following [Update jQuery to version 3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2533498)

> Now that jQuery 3.0 has been released jQuery 2.x will only be receiving security updates. I know what we've had discussions about updating specific libraries in the past. But there are a few compelling reasons why we should consider updating jQuery to 3.x